# Getting CrashLoopBackoff Error for apiserver & etcd in newly joined control plane node to the existing kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, devops, etcd, kubernetes-apiserver

We joined new control plain node to the existing kubernetes cluster
when i check the pods of new control plain node
kube-controller-manager & kube-scheduler are running fine
but etcd and kube-apiserver are CrashLoopBackOff

please find the logs of apiserver

```
kubectl logs kube-apiserver -n kube-system
Flag --insecure-port has been deprecated, This flag will be removed in a future version.
I1026 06:23:27.991788       1 server.go:625] external host was not specified, using serverIP
I1026 06:23:27.992596       1 server.go:163] Version: v1.19.16
I1026 06:23:28.279281       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1026 06:23:28.279305       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 10 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I1026 06:23:28.280325       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1026 06:23:28.280343       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 10 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I1026 06:23:28.282885       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "endpoint"
I1026 06:23:28.282948       1 endpoint.go:68] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}]
W1026 06:23:28.283539       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
I1026 06:23:29.277962       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "endpoint"
I1026 06:23:29.278012       1 endpoint.go:68] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}]
W1026 06:23:29.278309       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:29.283863       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:30.278671       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:30.708000       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:31.925477       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:33.481906       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:34.349865       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:37.895359       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:39.056593       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:45.305200       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1026 06:23:46.744018       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
Error: context deadline exceeded
```

please find the logs of etcd

```
# kubectl logs etcd -n kube-system
[WARNING] Deprecated '--logger=capnslog' flag is set; use '--logger=zap' flag instead
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919285 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.4.9
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919332 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 54ba674376
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919336 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.12.17
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919340 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919346 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 8, total number of available CPUs is 8
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919445 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
[WARNING] Deprecated '--logger=capnslog' flag is set; use '--logger=zap' flag instead
2022-10-26 06:25:32.919500 I | embed: peerTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key, trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-auth = true, crl-file =
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920218 I | embed: name = servername
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920229 I | embed: data dir = /var/lib/etcd
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920233 I | embed: member dir = /var/lib/etcd/member
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920236 I | embed: heartbeat = 100ms
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920240 I | embed: election = 1000ms
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920254 I | embed: snapshot count = 10000
2022-10-26 06:25:32.920286 I | embed: advertise client URLs = https://serverIP:2379
2022-10-26 06:25:32.921797 W | etcdserver: could not get cluster response from http://localhost:2380: Get http://localhost:2380/members: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2380: connect: connection refused
2022-10-26 06:25:32.922815 C | etcdmain: cannot fetch cluster info from peer urls: could not retrieve cluster information from the given URLs
```

Can anyone please guide me How to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 0):

Which container runtime are you using?  You can try to reset your kubeadm configuration by running `kubeadm reset` on all your control plan and worker nodes.  You can also look into your container logs within `/var/log/containers` and see what the errors are.